# How to test Spring REST webservice when using a HandlerInterceptorAdapter?

Tags: spring, testing, interceptor

I am developing a Spring web service. I want to test my endpoints but for some reason I always get the following exception when I run the tests:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.....IncomingInterceptor'
```

However, I annotated the class with `@Component`. The interceptor works when I test the endpoint using an external client! Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Here is my code when I test the endpoint:
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

```
@InjectMocks
private AccountController accountController;

@Mock
private IncomingInterceptor incomingInterceptor;

private Gson gson;

@Before
public void setup() {
    gson = new Gson();
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).addInterceptors(incomingInterceptor).build();
}

@Test
public void testAddAccount() throws 
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/account/add")
            .content(gson.toJson(account))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id").isNotEmpty());
}
```

The code for the IncomingInterceptor:

```
@Component
public class IncomingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Autowired
private Gson gson;

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
//code in here works
    return true;
}
}
```

Note: I do not want to test if the Interceptor works, I want to test the Endpoints!!!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Although your test code snippets do not reveal what test runner is used (`@RunWith(...)`), my guess is that you're using a `SpringRunner` or `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` test runner.*

Your snippet mocks an instance of `IncomingInterceptor`, however it isn't added to the `(test)ApplicationContext` as a bean. Use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock` to add your mocked bean to the `ApplicationContext`.

```
@MockBean
private IncomingInterceptor incomingInterceptor;
```

Comment: I am using Spring Runner --> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)